# react native - expo - libarchive.js "Can't find variable: Worker" issue

Tags: react-native, expo, libarchive

I am trying to unzip a file which exists in DocumentDirectoryPath but getting the error below:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: ReferenceError: Can't find variable:
> Worker]
>
> - node_modules\libarchive.js\src\libarchive.js:37:29 in Archive#constructor
> - node_modules\libarchive.js\src\libarchive.js:26:20 in Archive.open

my code below is very simple:

```
import { Archive } from 'libarchive.js/main.js';

 Archive.init({
      workerUrl: 'libarchive.js/dist/worker-bundle.js'
    });

const sourcePath =
      'file:///data/user/0/host.exp.exponent/files/ExperienceData/%2540testtest%252Ftest/testfile.zip';

    const archive = await Archive.open(sourcePath);
```

I would appreciate any ideas!

Answer (score 0):

libarchivejs works with [File](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/File) objects, so instead of passing file path you need to read the file and pass it to `Archive.open(fileObject)`

here's is examples of reading file

https://github.com/nika-begiashvili/libarchivejs#how-to-use